# JMeter - Ignore View Results Tree Listener only in non GUI

Tags: jmeter

Important [best practice](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) in not to use `View Results Tree`

> Don't use "View Results Tree" or "View Results in Table" listeners during the load test, use them only during scripting phase to debug your scripts.

Or any listeners:

> Use as few Listeners as possible; if using the -l flag as above they can all be deleted or disabled.

But `View Results Tree` is a great tool for debugging to identify issues in scripts.

Can we somehow ignore it only when running a non GUI mode?

I can ignore Sampler Result by [setIgnore](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setIgnore--) method, even ignore Thread Group by setting Number of Threads as 0 in property, can listener be ignored by property?

Currently I manually enable/disable in GUI before/after running in non GUI.

**EDIT**

But jmx files are saved in version control, so it should remain read only (used both for GUI and non GUI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say currently it is not possible with [classic non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) of test execution, the options are in:

1. Remove all the listeners from the test plan completely and control what is being stored in .jtl results file using [Results File Configuration Properties](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
2. Create a simple Java wrapper program to start a non-GUI JMeter test which will scan the Test Plan prior to starting and disable the listeners. It would be something like:

   ```
   StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();
   JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/path/to/your/jmeter.properties");
   JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("/path/to/your/jmeter");
   JMeterUtils.initLocale();
   SaveService.loadProperties();
   HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(new File("/path/to/your/testplan"));
   SearchByClass<ResultCollector> listenersSearch = new SearchByClass<>(ResultCollector.class);
   testPlanTree.traverse(listenersSearch);
   Collection<ResultCollector> listeners = listenersSearch.getSearchResults();
   listeners.forEach(listener -> listener.setProperty(TestElement.ENABLED, false));
   jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
   jmeter.run();
   ```
3. Use [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation) tool to run your test, it has [Modifications for Existing Scripts](http://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts) functionality so you will be able to disable listeners using simple declarative YAML syntax:

   ```
   ---
   execution:
     scenario:
       script: /path/to/your/testplan
       modifications:
         disable:  # Names of the tree elements to disable
         - View Results Tree
   ```