# JMeter - Execute specific components only on GUI and not CLI

Tags: debugging, jmeter, load-testing, disable

I add several components for debugging as `Debug Sampler`, `View Results Tree` and `JSR223 Sampler` that are useful in GUI mode, but I want it to be ignored when running load test,

Is there such option of executing Sampler/Listener only in GUI mode and not in command line/"load" mode?

Comment: I was looking for the same. Turned out you may need to write regex to mark the tree node in jmx as disable or to use https://gettaurus.org/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51056678/1115090. AFAIK, No alternative apart from this. I will write about what I meant by first point once I get back to home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround, to send in CLI JMeter property as -JignoreFirstSampler

Add If Controller as a parent of samplers to exclude checking if [property is defined](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__isPropDefined)

```
 ${__isPropDefined(ignoreFirstSampler)}
```

> The __isPropDefined function returns true if property exists or false if not.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is the exact answer you are looking for but still let me try. We know that JMeter script is nothing but xml in disguise and structure look like this.

[image]

So for every Jmeter component, there is `enable` property which needs to be `true` so that it will get executed as part of JMeter Test plan. Now if we can change this some properties which can be passed as parameter then we can make them disable at the run time.
Change in jmx will be reflected like this...

[image]

If you run this script in Non GUI mode with additional property passed as parameter, we essentially achieve what we want.

```
jmeter -n -t .\ExcludeJMeterComponent.jmx -l result.CSV -e -o "Output" -DenabledDebugComponents=false
```

Issue with this approach is, **if you load this script again in JMeter, these values, manually edited `jmx`  going to go away/get override with your next save but if you are using any version control system to keep track of your `jmx` script [which you must be doing] it will be very easy to add this changes in the script again in no time.**

I will post this with more details once my blog is set up.

Comment: jmx should work also in GUI, so add a default value? as `${__P(enabledDebugComponents,true)}`

Comment: jmx will work in GUI, you may find the components are disabled and you can toggle them as you normally do but on **Save** they will override the property name that we setup manually to consume from command line but VCS keeping track of change in jmx it should b easy to revert when committing again

Comment: Can the components in GUI be enabled with such approach?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, can you please elaborate more? Also setting default value for property doesn't helped me :)

Comment: I want the GUI mode to execute listener/debug by default, but your solution will disable all istener/debug and I'll have to manually everytime enable it

Comment: I agree that solution is not resolve your problem. All the best

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195265/discussion-between-amol-and-user7294900).

Comment: all the best, which OS do you use anyway ?

Comment: Windows and Linux